# Do you lose records when you reconfigure mongodb replicaset?

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

I have 3 member replicaSet in MongoDB which fell apart when re-configuring the host names of the sever instances. I had to reconfigure the replicaSet, however I am curious how MongoDB handles records that are not synced across all the members.

Case 1) There is a new record on the MongoDB server that I access to reconfigure the set.
Case 2) There is a new record on another MongoDB server that is added later to the replica set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each replica-set has one primary node and one or more secondary nodes.

**All** writes happen on the primary. The primary then sends these changes to the secondaries (the list of changes is referred to as "the oplog"). That means the primary is always the member with the most up-to-date data.

When the primary is suddenly unreachable, the replica-set is put into read-only mode and an election takes place to find a new primary. Usually the secondary which is most up-to-date is selected (more details on [replica-set election](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/)). Any writes which were not propagated to that secondary yet are lost.

When the old primary goes back online, it re-joins the replica-set as a secondary. Its data gets synchronized to the state of the new primary. Any writes which only happened on the old primary which weren't propagated to the new primary before the crash are rolled back.

The rolled-back writes are backed up as bson-files in the directory `/rollback` and can be re-added to the replica-set using [bsondump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/bsondump/) and [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore). Details about this procedure can be found in the article [Rollbacks During Replica Set Failover](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/)

Comment: The old writes are not lost they are factored off into files for manual merging, otherwsie known as a rollback scenario

Comment: It might be worth making reference to what can happen in a [**rollback**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) situation as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn heh does seem that way

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you. I added that to the answer.